# how to check status of checkboxes in gridview columns on click of button

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, webforms

T have used checkbox column in gridview. On click of a linkbutton, it should be checked that checkboxes in gridview are checked or not. If none check box is checked then it should display alert("Check at leat one check box").

Comment: why tagged with C# and asp.net if it's a javascript question?

Comment: Actually i was new to development at that time. so i was thinking that javascript works differently for different langueges at that time. So i just wanted to tell that i m using c# and asp.net and need help for javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. and its working...

function checkBoxselectedornot()
    {

```
       var frm=document.forms['aspnetForm'];
       var flag=false;
       for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)
       {
           if(document.forms[0].elements[i].id.indexOf('chkDownloadSelectedEvent')!=-1)
           {
                 if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked)
                 {
                      flag=true
                 }  
           }
       } 
      if (flag==true)
      {
        return true
      }else
      {
        alert('Please select at least one Event.')
        return false
      }

}
```

and girdview code is...

```
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width ="100px" DataField ="EventStartDate" DataFormatString ="{0:g}" HeaderText ="<%$ Resources:stringsRes, ctl_EventList_StartDate %>" SortExpression ="EventStartDate" HtmlEncode ="true" ItemStyle-Wrap ="false" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="EventDate" DataFormatString="{0:g}" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:stringsRes, ctl_EventList_Date %>"  SortExpression="EventDate" HtmlEncode="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
            <asp:ButtonField ItemStyle-Width="150px" ButtonType="Link" DataTextField="EventName" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:stringsRes, ctl_EventList_Event %>"  SortExpression="EventName" CommandName="show_details" CausesValidation="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventLocation" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:stringsRes, ctl_EventList_Location %>" SortExpression="EventLocation" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Select">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDownloadSelectedEvent" runat ="server" AutoPostBack ="false" Onclick="eachCheck();"/>                   

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle Height="25px" />
        <HeaderStyle Height="30px"/>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and there is a link button ....

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add some custom Javascript to your page for the client-side alert to show. Here's a method that I've written that works with a GridView called 'GridView1' (this should be the default name if you've just dragged the control onto your ASPX page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClientCheck() {
        var valid = false;
        var gv = document.getElementById("GridView1");

        for (var i = 0; i < gv.all.length; i++) {
            var node = gv.all[i];
            if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!valid) {
            alert("Invalid. Please select a checkbox to continue.");
        }

        return valid;
    }
</script>
```

You can see that it sets a variable to the `GridView` control to start with, then iterates through all the children in a `for` loop. If the child is a `checkbox` and it is `checked`, then we set the `valid` variable to true. If we get to the end of the iteration and no checked checkboxes are found, then `valid` remains false and we execute the alert.

To link this into your `GridView` on your ASPX page, first make the button column a `TemplateField` and surround the `LinkButton` with your client-side code. If you've used the designer to set up your columns, you can use the "Convert this field into a TemplateField" link in the column editor). Here's an example of the source you'll end up with:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Button Field" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span onclick="return ClientCheck();">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="IDClick" Text='<%# Eval("YourDataSourceItem") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        // ...your remaining columns...
```

Using the `TemplateField` lets us add any client-side code we like. Here we're adding a `span` and using `onclick` to call our `ClientCheck` method.

If you aren't bothered about the alert, you could achieve your aims by using a `CustomValidator` control, which executes on the server-side.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I havnt used the checkbox in grid view but would you not do a for loop around the columns in gridview and check the state? Myabe add a count and if 0 then alert.

Comment: yes. but it is possible on server side. I have to do it in java script. And checkboxes are not accessed as they are in Item Template of gridview.

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = document.getElementById("gridId");  //Retrieve the grid    
    var inputs = grid.getElementsByTagName("input"); //Retrieve all the input elements from the grid
    var isValid = false;
    for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) { //Iterate over every input element retrieved
        if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox") { //If the current element's type is checkbox, then it is wat we need
            if(inputs[i].checked === true) { //If the current checkbox is true, then atleast one checkbox is ticked, so break the loop
                isValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!isValid) {
        alert('Check at least one checkbox');
    }
```

Comment: Thanx but still checkbox can not be accessed.