# Validating checkboxes present inside gridview with Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 checkboxes in a GridView. I want to validate them with JavaScript.
This is my aspx code...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsExist">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkExists" runat="server" Text="Exists" AutoPostBack="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Not Exists In Update">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkExistsInUpdate" runat="server" Text="NotExists" AutoPostBack="false"/>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And my JavaScript condition is:

```
function check_one() {
            var obj = document.form1;
            if (obj.chkExists.checked == true || obj.chkExistsInUpdate.checked == true) {
                alert("Plese check only one checkbox...");
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
```

But I don't know that how to access the checkboxes from GridView on the client side? Please suggest an example.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349055/how-to-check-status-of-checkboxes-in-gridview-columns-on-click-of-button

Comment: or check this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewcheckBoxes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
MyGridView = document.getElementById('<%= this.MyGridView.ClientID %>');
var Inputs = MyGridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
var chkBox = "chkExists";
for(var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
     if(Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && 
        Inputs[n].id.indexOf(chkBox,0) >= 0 && 
        Inputs[n].checked)

      return true;
```

Similarly you can check for the other checkbox too...

Comment: My checkbox are in front of each other.. so ur code not working

Comment: Front of each other.. lol.. dude.. just post clear questions, else don't expect the answers.